# sudzc not getting in handler

Tags: xml, soap, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios4

I am using sudzc to call a webservice.
Everything goes great and he prints the whole soap xml result i get back, but before calling the method: handler method i get this error message: (you see also the prove he closes the soap envelope, so i got what i want but he dont want to finish it)

...

```
</SynGETResponse></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
2010-12-08 17:43:34.656 SudzCExamples[761:207] +[NSMutableArray newWithNode:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x26c4bdc
2010-12-08 17:43:34.658 SudzCExamples[761:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[NSMutableArray newWithNode:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x26c4bdc'
*** Call stack at first throw:
(
 0   CoreFoundation                      0x0265bb99 __exceptionPreprocess + 185
 1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x027ab40e objc_exception_throw + 47
 2   CoreFoundation                      0x0265d76b +[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 187
 3   CoreFoundation                      0x025cd2b6 ___forwarding___ + 966
 4   CoreFoundation                      0x025cce72 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 50
 5   SudzCExamples                       0x000023da -[SDZArrayOfArrayOfKnoop initWithNode:] + 297
 6   SudzCExamples                       0x0001a79d -[SoapRequest connectionDidFinishLoading:] + 985
 7   Foundation                          0x001c6b96 -[NSURLConnection(NSURLConnectionReallyInternal) sendDidFinishLoading] + 108
 8   Foundation                          0x001c6aef _NSURLConnectionDidFinishLoading + 133
 9   CFNetwork                           0x02aeb72f _ZN19URLConnectionClient23_clientDidFinishLoadingEPNS_26ClientConnectionEventQueueE + 285
 10  CFNetwork                           0x02bb6fcf _ZN19URLConnectionClient26ClientConnectionEventQueue33processAllEventsAndConsumePayloadEP20XConnectionEventInfoI12XClientEvent18XClientEventParamsEl + 389
 11  CFNetwork                           0x02ae0968 _ZN19URLConnectionClient13processEventsEv + 100
 12  CFNetwork                           0x02ae07e5 _ZN17MultiplexerSource7performEv + 251
 13  CoreFoundation                      0x0263cfaf __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 15
 14  CoreFoundation                      0x0259b39b __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 571
 15  CoreFoundation                      0x0259a896 __CFRunLoopRun + 470
 16  CoreFoundation                      0x0259a350 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 208
 17  CoreFoundation                      0x0259a271 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 97
 18  GraphicsServices                    0x02dae00c GSEventRunModal + 217
 19  GraphicsServices                    0x02dae0d1 GSEventRun + 115
 20  UIKit                               0x00433af2 UIApplicationMain + 1160
 21  SudzCExamples                       0x00001e12 main + 104
 22  SudzCExamples                       0x00001da1 start + 53
 23  ???                                 0x00000001 0x0 + 1
```

Where do i have to look at? Please help...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why, but it looks like you have the wrong type.

If you grep the source code in the Generated/Soap directory, you'll see that

```
+ (id) newWithNode: (CXMLNode*) node
```

is defined in several files, most likely Generated/Soap/SoapArray.h was the one that was intended.

I'd try contacting sudzc.com directly, posting your WSDL, and asking politely for help.